# Dificuldade com programa de numero triangular

Tags: c

Estou com dificuldade na criação de um programa que imprime se o numero digitado é triangular ou não. Como devo proceder para criar dentro da condicional uma sequencia indefinida para um numero grande?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int num, i, aux;
    scanf("%d", &num);

    num = n*(n + 1)/2;

        for(i = 1; i + (i + 1)<=num; i++ )
            {

                if(i + (i + 1) + (i + 2) == num)
                aux = 1;

            }
        if (aux) 
            {
                printf("SIM");
            }
        else
            {
                printf("NAO");
            }   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A variavel `aux` nao foi inicializada.

Answer (score 2):

Esse caso é bem fácil e básico. Para um número ser triangular ele precisa ser uma soma finita. Logo, a "subtração" finita tem resultado zero.

Você pode fazer um looping por [recursividade](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade):

```
char triangular(int numero) //Leia-se bool
{
    static unsigned int counter = 1
    if( (numero - counter) == 0 && numero != 1) return 1; //Se a subtração for zero e se o número não for 1
    else if( (numero - counter) < 0) //Caso a subtração for menor que zero (não triangular)
    {
        counter = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    else //Caso a subtração for positiva (há mais o que fazer)
    {
        counter++;
        return triangular(numero + 1 - counter);
    }
}
```

Ou, também, você pode usar a fórmula [(n² + n) / 2](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_triangular) a seu "favor" e calcular a raiz quadrada da possível equação. Dos dois resultados, um é eliminado (negativo) e outro pode ser exato ou inexato. Se for exato, é triangular.

PS.: O segundo método não é definitivo embora seja mais rápido. O primeiro método é mais confiável.